# How to destroy lost android phones?

Tags: lost-phone

I am living in Afghanistan and here too many things get stolen every day especially mobile phones. Therefore, I want to know a way that if my phone gets stolen, it gets destroyed.

Is there any possible way I could do this?

Comment: The answer Below is good. I personally hope you mean get the thing to blow up, but that would be hard :)

Comment: Why not consider encryption?

Answer (score 2):

No, I do not think there is a possible way to remotely completely destroy a phone, but other things you could do are:

- Track and find your lost phone
- Lock it (Put a remote password so the thief cannot access it)
- Ring it (Make it make a loud sound so if the thief is nearby, you will notice)
- Wipe it (Delete everything on the phone except the [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system))

You can do all of these things through the [Google Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) or another anti-theft [Play Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) application but they require your phone to be turned on and it to have an internet connection.